# Media Player Classic HC (K-Lite Codecs) Mutes my system when playing some files

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, media-player, digital-audio

As the title states, I'm trying to play some videos in K-Lite Codec Pack (12.0.1) MPC-HC (1.7.10.101), and when the track is playing my system stops being able to produce sound on my speakers. (pause playback and sound returns to normal)

I'm running sound through HDMI on an Nvidia (670) Graphics card with stereo speakers connected to my TV.

In MPC-HC I am using the MadVR renderer (not related, since that's video), and the LAV Audio splitter and decoder.

The soundtrack's format is 6-channel DTS.

6 Channel AAC sound works fine (downmixes to stereo and plays)

So I am guessing it is the format that is causing this.

Anyone got any ideas what could be going on here? Please let me know in the comments if there is information I missed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but apparently when DTS was ticked as a digital bitstreaming format in LAV Audio Decoder this happened. When I unticked it sound plays normally again and all is well.

[image: Untick DTS in LAV Audio Decoder]

I'd realy like to know why this happens so an answer that would provide the reason (as I initially asked) would be great and will be accepted over this one.

Comment: "Bitstreaming" means LAV will not decode the track and send it directly through S/PDIF or HDMI. You only want that if you are connecting to an amplifier or so that is capable of decoding it. I've never seen any TV can decode DTS streams, not even Dolby streams, at least not streams from HDMI inputs (instead of broadcast signals).

Comment: @TomYan Ah I see. Funny thing is; I am connected to a DTS capable amplifier, just not with digital (amplifier connected by stereo to TV which is connected to HDMI on computer)

Thanks!